# How to create reflection class in java and is there any possible way to pass more than two class as argument

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass more than two class in code given below

```
getMethod(methodName, new Class[] { rootBean.getClass() })
```

and I want to create object from argument class so that I can call method of arugment class.

```
if(obj==null) { 
    ClassA.getMethod((methodName, new Class[] { rootBean.getClass() }));
} else {
    // other operation
}
```

Comment: You should use Reflection to work with existing objects (instances of Classes).

Comment: I don't see any code "given below." Give us a bit more.

Comment: Dear Germann Arlington thank you for your suggestion. Dear David P.Caldwell, I have updated code please have a look on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
getMethod(methodName, new Class[] { rootBean.getClass(), Otherbean.class });
```

however [Class#getMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) takes a variable length argument, so no need to create an array, just pass you class agrument separated by comma

```
getMethod(methodName, rootBean.getClass(), OtherBean.class);
```